# Certificate verification

Tags: certificates

I work on a desktop application which generates Security certificates. The Business use of these certificates is - they will be used as an authentication and authorization mechanism to enable users to login to remote machines. The certificates will be copied to a USB token which in turn will be connected to a laptop.
I need to verify if the generated certificate is valid and if the certificate is accepted by the System. I would like to have suggestions on how I can test the certificate in terms of validity and acceptance.

Comment: This is very vague. What kind of certificates? x509 client certs? What do you mean by "if the certificate is accepted by the system"? You also haven't said what kind of validation you're expecting to be done on the client - is this something you want to do programmatically inside an application, or with a standalone tool? Please go back and edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: Yes the certificates generated are x509 client certificates. By "if the certificate is accepted by the system", I mean I would like to verify if the certificate is allowed to be installed in the System and Internet Explorer. I would like to verify this for both - a valid certificate and an invalid certificate. I would like to do this both programmatically inside an application as well as using a standalone tool. Please suggest method for the above.